# Adding metrics to JMX

Tags: monitoring, jmx, metrics

What can you measure in your application using JMX?
Is it possible to add metrics to JMX? For instance: seeing how much time a certain operation took?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add whatever metrics you like, you decide what you want to monitor.

For the second question, yes you can measure how much time some operation take.

One easy to implement your JMX metrics is to use Spring annotations :

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jmx-exporting

Comment: And if we are not using Spring?